# Problem in executing gpio shell via PHP

Tags: gpio, php, bash

I was trying to execute gpio[bash shell] command from PHP. I was executing properly as expected, but when I cross check the same with bash shell pin 0 values got changed.
*1. input url :gpio.php?value=4 [working and output displayed as expected toggle happens]
2. bash shell : #gpio read 4 [doesn't change the value, only pin 0 changes]*

```
$num = intval($_GET['value']);
echo $num;
if (isset($num)){
        $read = shell_exec('gpio read ".$num."');
        if($read == 0) {
                echo "OFF";
                $re = shell_exec('gpio write ".$num." 1');}
        if($read == 1) {
                echo "ON";
                $re = shell_exec('gpio write ".$num." 0');}

        $read = shell_exec('gpio read ".$num."');
        if($read == 0) {echo " --> OFF";}
        if($read == 1) {echo " --> ON";}
        }
else {echo "No value Found";}
```

Let me known were I'm wrong...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PHP is rusty (to say the least).

I would use

```php
$cmd = "gpio write $num 1";
$re = shell_exec($cmd);
```

or possibly just

```php
$re = shell_exec("gpio write $num 1");
```

Comment: Only pin 0 changes value

Comment: There is no such thing as pin 0.  I suggest you echo to the output the value you are trying to shell exec.  That should show what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please list pins? I've used python to execute other gpio functions

Comment: @jOSe The library you use will define the method used to number the GPIO.  Check its documentation.  Most will let you specify the GPIO by their Broadcom number.  See my diagram at the end of http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html for the association of Broadcom GPIO number to pin number on the expansion header.